# AWS Bucket File Cleanup (Deletion)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, bucket

We have a AWS bucket NPI_Recovery_Tool, which contains two folders Input and Output. We have set up one expiration policy to cleanup the file after every 30 days of file creation in Input and Output folder.
Under file cleanup policy configuration we have set the prefix and tabs as NPI_Recovery_Tool/Input, as we need to delete the file under Input folder. But it deleted the entire NPI_Recovery_Tool folder. Please help and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, I assume the below things for my answer.
Bucket Name: **NPI_Recovery_Tool**

Two folders created inside this bucket: **Input** and **Output**

Note: While adding prefix, you should not include bucket name

So if you want to delete the files under Input folder the prefix should be **Input**

FYI: S3 is always a key object store, and folders constitute the name of the key while accessing any objects inside it.

References:

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys

Comment: great.. But what if I have buket structure like this Phynder/NPI_Recovery_Tool/Input/ .. so then prefix would be NPI_Recovery_Tool/Input/ correct ?

Comment: If your bucket name is **Phynder** , then yes the prefix would be **NPI_Recovery_Tool/Input/**